# How to Get Sunday of any day

Tags: java, android

i have an issue with get day in android. in my activity i have a button, when i tap this button, my current day will Increased to 1 day and the last day is sunday.
If i tap the button, until the current day increases past the next week, the last day will be the next Sunday of the following week. My code works properly when I click the first time, when i tap my button again my current day is up to 7 days, I did the research but did not find the results as expected. Hope you can help. 
Example like this:
Every time i press the button:

MONDAY 5/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

TUESDAY 6/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

WEDNESDAY 7/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

THURSDAY 8/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

FRIDAY 9/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

SATURDAY 10/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

SUNDAY 11/6/2017 - SUNDAY 11/6/2017

MONDAY 12/6/2017 - SUNDAY 18/6/2017

TUESDAY 13/6/2017 - SUNDAY 18/6/2017

........

this is my code:
Thank you in advance.

```
     btnChooseDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
                    tvDayChoose.setText(getNameOfDay(mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) + ", " + mSimpleDateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
                    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY );
                    tvDayChoose.append(" - " + mSimpleDateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
                }
            });
```

Comment: do you mean, increase the day until the sunday of the week after current date? i'm quite confused here

Comment: Increase start date to 1 day, end date is Sunday of the week, thank you for you anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost everything right. You setting and fetching date correctly, However , you are doing it on same date by this line (`mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY );`. As a result, you are getting into loop. 
Lets say today is june 5  ( monday), so when you first add 1, it becomes june 6(tuesday), so your sunday date is june 4 which you set back to your date. Now, you mCalendar is set to June 4, and when you click again,you add 1 and it becomes june 5 and your sunday becomes June 4 again, and you set that to your mCalendar again, which sets it back to june 4. This keeps repeating for ever. So your solution is to use `new Calendar instance` to get sunday , but keep adding 1 on the `mCalendar`.  You may find better way to create calendar instance,but make few changes like to keep things in proper state :

Add this two line after you add 1 on `mCalendar` ,

```
Calendar sundayCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    sundayCalendar.setTime(mCalendar.getTime());
```

Then set Sunday date in this `new Calendar instance` and use it , instead of using `mCalenar`. Now your `mCalendar` keeps it state of increment and `sundayCalendar` returns your sunday date based on `mCalendar` which is incremented by 1 on every click.

```
 sundayCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, mCalendar.get(Calendar.SUNDAY));

 tvDayChoose.append(" - " + mSimpleDateFormat.format(sundayCalendar.getTime()));
```

A simple class to show usage is as below :

```
public class DateSunday {

static Calendar mCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();

public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        onClick();
    }
}

public static void onClick(){
    SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

    Calendar sundayCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    sundayCalendar.setTime(mCalendar.getTime());
    sundayCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, mCalendar.get(Calendar.SUNDAY));

    System.out.println(" - " + mSimpleDateFormat.format(sundayCalendar.getTime()));

    }
}
```

Comment: It working great with me, thanks you for save my day.